# Unexpected something (a gap?) between perfectly aligned elements in Chrome on mobile

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I noticed that if I use Chrome on mobile or switch it to mobile mode on a desktop (in developer tools) it renders something between perfectly aligned divs without gaps (see the screenshots attached). Steps to reproduce are very easy just use this HTML code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        div > div {
            font-size: 2rem;
            padding: 2rem;
            background-color: cornflowerblue;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="div2">
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is it a Chrome bug? I was trying to find something but failed. It is very annoying. Is there any workaround?

[image: Screenshot in normal mode]

[image: Screenshot with mobile development on]

Comment: Yep this happened in my screen too.

Comment: This is just a chrome glitch, I don't think it'll happen on mobile devices.

Comment: Actually, it _happens_ on a device

Answer (score -1):

One solution would be to color the background of the parent container.

```
#div2 {
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
}
```

Comment: That's not a solution as it doesn't solve the problem, just adds some makeup to it.

Comment: The problem is the lines, yeah? This fixes that. It's a workaround, as was requested by the OP. I'm not sure what else you are expecting.

Comment: It's not a solution if I want to use 3 different colors. Which color should I take for background in that case? Whatever I choose it would be at least one line.

Comment: You didn't specify that in the question... but you can add a div with :before, positioned absolute, height 1px, width 100%, color whatever the parent div is.